# client IP is different each page reload in heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, ip

I'm trying to get the client IP as a way to save a particular user so the server knows who they are next time they visit, without having the need to login/signup for anything. This is a React front end with a NodeJS backend.

I tried my app locally and it seems to work fine. But I tried deploying it to Heroku and now I'm getting different IP addresses each time I reload. It keeps the same IP for the duration of the visit, but once I reload (refresh) the page, my IP changes..

```
[Method: 'POST'] [Path: '/api/posts'] [IP '::ffff:***.63.***.219']
[Method: 'POST'] [Path: '/api/posts'] [IP '::ffff:***.47.***.144']
```

(actual ip modified)

this is my console, as you can see the IP is completely different, and it looks nothing like my IP. I'm getting the IP from the request object (request.ip).

Why is the IP different each time on Heroku but stable on my local machine? is there another method for getting the client IP that I should be using? or is this a Heroku problem? I've looked for answers about this but I have come up empty which makes me think this is specific to Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Heroku Documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing), all requests are going through a Proxy which acts mainly as a load balancer (If I have it correct in mind). You can use the [custom HTTP-Headers](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#heroku-headers) to get the client ip address, but *it is not recommended*!

Additional:
For security reasons you should avoid to use the IP to identify a user, because that can cause session hijacking. Use technologies like cookies instead!

Comment: I need a way to identify the user without them being able to manipulate it. (of course a VPN could manipulate their ip but I don't know of a way around that) They can delete cookies and local storage, I don't want them to be able to. I want a way to identify the user no matter what they do to try to hide it (aside from VPN)

Comment: Your are looking for something like a supercookie. The problem is that nobody is on your side. That means that all common browser manufactures like Mozilla, Google, etc. implements features that prevents websites to fully track a user. According to my information, there is no technology to track a user to 100%. You can search for something like "canvas fingerprinting" or "favicon supercookie", but the manufactures blocks them as good as possible.

Comment: I don't want to actually 'track' them. but when they post a message, I generate a random ID and assign it to that IP. then whoever posts from that IP will post with that ID. I don't like the idea of canvas fingerprinting or favicon super cookies. This was the simplest solution I could come up with. 

seeing as you answered the question though I'm going to pick this as the answer, I guess my solution works, just not on heroku.